# Notificação de reputação parece não estar funcionando

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

Percebi que as notificações de reputação pararam de aparecer no menu, no ícone do troféu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pontuação é contada normalmente, inclusive alterando o valor da reputação na barra, e é exibida normalmente na aba de reputação do perfil:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que tem alguma relação com a atualização do layout do site que aconteceria/acontecerá hoje?

Comment: Aqui também parou hj no meio da manhã

Comment: Vira e mexe acontece isso. Me parece sempre temporário mesmo.

Comment: No app mobile também não aparecem as notificações

Comment: Publicação no Meta: [“Recent Achievements” popup/badge is not updating](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374534/1452488)

Comment: Ainda tá a acontecer, @AndersonCarlosWoss?

Comment: @JNat aparentemente não, foi voltando aos poucos e agora parece estar normal.